# Set initial orientation to either landscape left or landscape right for iOS

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that only supports a landscape view.  I can specify that the initial orientation be either landscape-left or landscape-right.  However if I specify, for example, landscape-left and the user is holding the device so that the home button is on the right, then my app will first be displayed upside down, and then rotate to the correct orientation after it has launched.  I want to be able to set it so that it will default to either left or right depending on how the user is holding the device.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it default to the correct orientation if you don't specify anything, once you've enabled landscape mode?

Comment: Well I tried removing the initial orientation setting but it then formatted the page as portrait.  The thing is complicated by the fact that it is both an iPhone and iPad app and the iPhone version supports all orientations, but the iPad version only support landscape.

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 4+, you could use `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` to check if it's running on the iPad. If so, then set landscape mode on . If it's on the iPhone, allow all, but don't force landscape (i.e. whatever you're currently doing for iPhone)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  After your first comment I went back and tried removing the specific initial orientation settings (which was what I tried first before) and this time was able to get it to work.  I must have mucked up the info.plist file somehow last time.  Anyway I seem to have it working now. Thanks