# How to start a landscape iOS app in the correct orientation without rotating?

Tags: ios, rotation, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

I'm developing a landscape-only, iPhone-only iOS6+ app and having problems getting the rotation to work as I want it to.

The only supported interface orientations set for the app target are Landscape Left and Right. I only have a single view controller at the moment, with its `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` method simply returning `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`. The info.plist file does not have the `UIInterfaceOrientation` key.

What I'd like to happen is that after the launch image disappears and the initial view controller is displayed, it is immediately displayed correctly in the orientation in which the user is holding the device, no animations.

What is happening instead is that if the user holds the phone with the home button on the right, the interface is drawn upside down, and then autorotated to match the device rotation. The phone automatically prefers one landscape mode over the other, and I need it to prefer neither (or at least APPEAR to prefer neither, even if this means the use of trickery is needed.)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751956/set-initial-orientation-to-either-landscape-left-or-landscape-right-for-ios) seems to be asking the same thing, although the use case there is somewhat different, and it's unanswered.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Try removing and setting again. That's what his comment says in the attached link. -> _"Thanks for the suggestion. After your first comment I went back and tried removing the specific initial orientation settings (which was what I tried first before) and this time was able to get it to work. I must have mucked up the info.plist file somehow last time. Anyway I seem to have it working now. Thanks –"_

Comment: It wasn't there to begin with, and it didn't work back then either. I added and removed it later on, but to no avail.